# accessing all non zero entries of a csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
M=csr_matrix((5,5))
M[2,3]=4
```

I would like to iterate all non-zero entries, something like:

```
for x,y,v in M.non_zero_entries:
   do_something()
```

I try to comprehend the values of `M.data`,`M.indices` and `M.indptr`

Now, in the example above:

```
print (M.data) #outputs [4]
print (M.indices) #outputs [3]
print (M.indptr) #outputs [0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

How can I extract the non-zero records from that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are (were) looking for is the [nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero) method:

> **csr_matrix.nonzero()**
>
> Returns a tuple of arrays (row,col) containing the indices of the
> non-zero elements of the matrix.

So your loop would be like this:

```
for row, col in zip(*M.nonzero()):
    val = M[row, col]
    # do something
    print((row, col), val)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `M.tocoo()` which returns a "coordinate-format" version of the matrix, which has vectors `data`, `row` and `col` which you use in the "obvious" way.

Or you could do it by hand. Something like this (WARNING: tested on exactly one example, and I've given no thought to efficiency):

```
def csr_entries(M):
    """Generator of tuples (i,j,x) of sparse matrix entries
    meaning that M[i,j]=x."""
    for row in range(len(M.indptr)-1):
        i,j = M.indptr[row],M.indptr[row+1]
        for k in range(i,j):
            yield (row, M.indices[k], M.data[k])
```